# SSRS 22017 passing a parameter value to a url

Tags: report, url-parameters, ssrs-2017

Hi I have been trying to pass a value in to another report via a URL link, but cannot get the syntax correct, I have trawled the net and the 8 questions already in Stack and tweaked my code for each answer but cannot get it right.

I have a fully developed report that used a parameter "**SALES_ORDER**" you manually enter the SALES order and the report runs ok.

I have another report that is a graph of the above data with the sales order as the key to both.The graph is showing the last 10 sales orders by sales order number , when I click on the sales order number I want to be taken to the URL of the original developed report taking the sales order I clicked in in the graph so the original report uses this as the parameter.

The code for the jump to in the action box of the graph is :

```
="http://SERVER_NAME/Reports/report/GEMINI%20REPORTING/BY%20DEPARTMENT/PP/Manual%20Production_order_tracker_V31&rs:Command=render&SALES_ORDER="+Fields!SOPT_SALES_ORD.Value
```

**SSRS** likes the code as the graph report runs ok, I can click on the required bar for the specific sales order It then opens the correct URL page but I get the error below:

> "The path of the item '/GEMINI REPORTING/BY DEPARTMENT/PP/Manual
>   Production_order_tracker_V31&rs:Command=render&SALES_ORDER=2900252422'
>   is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long;
>   other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the
>   path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) Get Online Help "

The parameter in the developed report is "**SALES_ORDER**".

I know I could duplicate the developed report and include it in the "new project" I am working within but that then means for any change to the developed report I have to make the same changes to the one in the new project, hence wanting to hyperlink to it.

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Tony King

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action as Go to Report and give your Report name and Then therein you can give Parameter name and it's Value?

Screenshot for Reference

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment,m the "specify a report" will only show you reports that are within your project, my "jump to" report is in a different project.

Comment: I dont want to duplicate the original report I am jumping to hence using the URL refrence.

Comment: Ahhh ok. As mentioned you already tried most of the things. Try below URL

`="http://SERVER_NAME/Reports/report/GEMINI%20REPORTING/BY%20DEPARTMENT/PP/Manual%20Production_order_tracker_V31&rs:Command=render&SALES_ORDER="&Fields!SOPT_SALES_ORD.Value`

Comment: Yes, I think my code just needs a little tweak as the tail end of it, but just cannot work it out :(. Thank you tho. T

Comment: I Tried your code and received the same error :The path of the item '/GEMINI REPORTING/BY DEPARTMENT/PP/Manual Production_order_tracker_V31&rs:Command=render&SALES_ORDER=2900252487' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) Get Online Help. You can see it pulls over the correct sales order number, but just wint pass it in to the other report, its not because the parameter value is not hidden is it ?

Comment: can you try manually giving static url in browser or so and see if you reach to Report. May be without any parameter

Comment: Yes it does if I just enter the URL in the action I open the required URLup and it then awaits a sales order to be entered, I enter it manulay and it works.

Comment: Does anyone have any further infromation, stil ltrawling the net and forums for this but still get the same error :( TK